# vba Error when using find on a concatenated string variable

Tags: vba

[Data1 content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2o7S.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMNNr.jpg)
Would like to ask for help on the following code in vba. Basically, I concatenated the caption of a label (Date) with a textbox value (EmpNo) from userform so I don't have to search for each item in 2 separate columns (EmpNo in column B and date in column C) and stored this in string variable  Data1. Then I want to find where Data1 is in column A and get the 7th column to the right. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this but it keeps sending an error object variable or with block variable not set.

Error is showing up in the `Set Search=Range ...` line.

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Data1 As String
    Dim Search As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Pass As Range
    D1.Caption = Range("R4").Text
    D2.Caption = Range("R5").Text
    D3.Caption = Range("R6").Text
    D4.Caption = Range("R7").Text
    D5.Caption = Range("R8").Text
    D6.Caption = Range("R9").Text
    D7.Caption = Range("R10").Text
        Data1 = EmpNo.Text & "-" & D3.Caption
        Set Cell = Range("K4: K1000").Find(EmpNo.Text).Offset(0, 3)
        Set Pass = Range("K4: K1000").Find(EmpNo.Text).Offset(0, 1)
        Set Search = Range("A4: A1000").Find(Data1).Offset(0, 7)
        EmpName.Caption = Cell.Text
    If Password.Text = Pass.Text Then MultiPage1.Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: excel]
[image: Code Screenshot with error]

Comment: Hi. I'm more into Access VBA, but as soon as you use an If-Then within a With statement, the outer With object expression is ignored.  Also, I wouldn't use Cell as a variable name.  Why not try putting a small 'v' in front of all your variables?  Like, vCell, vPass, vFormat?  I don't know if any of this will solve the issue, but maybe it will help!

Comment: Please tell us which line of code caused the error box.  Also post a screen shot of the Sheet1 so that we understand variable references.  Else, I would find it hard to reproduce the error on my excel.

Comment: This is the one that is causing the error                                                               
              Set Search = Range("A4:A1000").Find(Data1).Offset(0, 7)

Comment: @donPablo, edited the original post with link to screenshot

Comment: Your search term is not found.

Comment: I agree with SJR. Could you tell us which exact value you are searching for and which value in column A should have been a match in your opinion. The Find method has 9 arguments and you are using only one.

Comment: I'm storing EmpNo.Text (from the textbox userform)&"-"&D1.caption (from label in userform) in Data1. Then looking for it in Column A. Data1 is working fine I think. I dont know why search term is not found because I see it in the column :(

Comment: I've added screenshot in original post showing sample of data1 variable content which it should be able to find in column A

Comment: You're telling nothing we don't know already. The exact values we need.

Comment: sample value A-03-02

Comment: I've tried playing around with the code and saw that if Range("A4:A1000") are hard coded values, it works, but when values in column A are not hard coded, I get the error. Currently, Column A =Column B&"-"&Text(Column D,"mm-dd")

Comment: Start by addressing VBasic2008's point that Find has 9 arguments.